# Reference type inside dependency array of UseMemo hook in React

Tags: reactjs

Parent Component ->

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import List from './List.component';
 
const Counter = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);
  const [list, setList] = useState([3, 2, 1]);
 
 
  console.log('counter re-render');
 
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setTest(!test)}>123</button>
      <List items={list} />
    </>
  );
};
 
export default Counter;
```

Child Component

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
 
const List = ({ items }) => {
  const sortedItems = useMemo(
    function () {
      console.log('Sorting');
      return items.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    },
    [items]
  );
 
  console.log('List re-render');
 
  return (
    <ul>
      {sortedItems.map((item, ind) => (
        <li key={ind}>{item}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
 
export default List;
```

Here ouput is on initial render -> 1) Counter re-render , Sorting , List re-render . but then when I am updating "OUT OF THE BOX" state which is not related to my child component , output is -> 1)"Counter re-render" "List re-render" ( without sorting) .

my question is , why "Sorting" isn't on the output . and how useMemo dependency array is working under the hood . as I know it is using Object.is ( but after every render new List is created , so we have new reference and I was thinking that useMemo should be called on every render ( while we are updating "OUT OF THE BOX" state .

can someone help me to understand this topic deeply?

many thanks .

Answer (score 2):

> but after every render new List is created

This is where you are wrong. The `list` state is not recreated on every re-render. It is only created once when the `Counter` component is mounted. After that, unless you change the `list` state, it will not update. Since you are not calling `setList` anywhere, that is not happening, and hence you don't see "Sorting" logged to your console more than once.

Comment: Thanks , but then if I will wrap my component to Memo HOC . why this will still cause re-render my child component? why the reference is changing when I am wrapping it inside React.memo ?